# Sorting xslt nodes based on sibling

Tags: sorting, xslt, nodes

I am having some trouble getting this to work and I could really need some help.
I want to store the smallest variable that has a sibling which is not null.
I have a XML which looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <Item>
         <ValueOne>5</ValueOne>
         <Item>bababa</Item>
    </Item>
    <Item>
         <ValueOne>3</ValueOne>
         <Item>ababa</Item>
    </Item>
    <Item>
         <ValueOne>1</ValueOne>
         <Item/>
    </Item>
</Root>
```

I want the smallest ValueOne who's sibling Item has a value.
I was thinking something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="var">
    <xsl:for-each select="Root/Item">
         <xsl:if test="not(/Item = '')">
             <xsl:sort data-type="text"/>
             <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                 <xsl:value-of select="/Item"/>
             </xsl:if>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

But this doesn't work and I am not sure why. As you might tell I'm not the best at xslt. I cannot rename anything in the xml or change the structure of it.

Comment: In your example, there are no empty Items.The last Item/Item contains two line feeds and 9 spaces (or a tab?). That's legitimate payload, assuming you mean it. If not, you can use normalize-space to remove it. Please clarify.

Comment: I have edited the xml, there are no whitespaces, there are no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those spaces and returns are non-essential, you could use:

```
<xsl:variable name="var">
    <xsl:for-each select="Root/Item[normalize-space(Item)]">
        <xsl:sort select="ValueOne" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ValueOne)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

---

With all the redundant white space removed, this can be simplified to:

```
<xsl:variable name="var">
    <xsl:for-each select="Root/Item[Item/text()]">
        <xsl:sort select="ValueOne" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="ValueOne"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Sorry, they are not spaces, i was typing that a bit fast. Inte last Root/Item, Root/ITem/Item is supposed to be empty:
<Item>
     <ValueOne>2</ValueOne>
     <Item/>
</Item>

Will that still work though?

Comment: @user2235494 Please edit your *original* XML. Code in comments cannot be read reliably.